# Handle non-numeric data in python. Python beginner

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to replace all non-numeric data in a dataframe in Jupyter Notebook.

def handle_non_numerical_data(df):
    cols = df.columns.values

```
for col in cols:
    text_digit_vals = {}
    def covnert_to_int(val):
        return text_digit_vals[val]

    if df[col].dtype != np.int64 and df[col].dtype != np.float64:
        col_contents = df[col].values.tolist()
        unique_elements = set(col_contents)
        x = 0
        for unique in unique_elements:
            if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                x += 1

        df[col] = list(map(convert_to_int, df[col]))

return df
```

And then:

data_dropped_filled_numeric = handle_non_numerical_data(data_dropped_filled)

### Error:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 data_dropped_filled_numeric = handle_non_numerical_data(data_dropped_filled)

in handle_non_numerical_data(df)
     19                     x += 1
     20 
---> 21             df[col] = list(map(convert_to_int, df[col]))
     22 
     23     return df

NameError: name 'convert_to_int' is not defined

New to python. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: The `convert_to_int` function does not exist, since you have a typo in your definition. `def covnert_to_int`

Comment: It pays to understand the Error messages since they're there to help you debug your code. `NameError` only occurs when a `name` (in this case, a function name) is not defined. This immediately points you to a typo, using the wrong scope, or simply forgetting to define something

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your function definition:

```
 def covnert_to_int(val):
```

Change "covnert" to "convert"